# Update Command Executenonquery - Syntax Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-update, executenonquery

I tried to update some data in C# I got

> "Incorrect syntax near ')'." in line
>   "da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();".

I browsed code a lot of time, and I can't see error anymore. So in my opinion should be OK, but isn't. Could you look at below code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace klinika
{
    public partial class frModWla : Form
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Klinika; Integrated security=TRUE");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

        public frModWla()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnWyswietl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bindingClear();
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbWlasciciel", cs);
            ds.Clear();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

            bs.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

            tbxImie.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bs, "Imie"));
            tbxNazwisko.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bs, "Nazwisko"));
            tbxMiejscowosc.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bs, "Miejscowosc"));
            tbxKodPocztowy.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bs, "Kod_pocztowy"));
            tbxAdres.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bs, "Adres"));
            tbxTelefon.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bs, "Telefon"));
            tbxEmail.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bs, "Email"));

            rekord();

        }

        private void bindingClear()
        {
            tbxImie.DataBindings.Clear();
            tbxNazwisko.DataBindings.Clear();
            tbxMiejscowosc.DataBindings.Clear();
            tbxKodPocztowy.DataBindings.Clear();
            tbxAdres.DataBindings.Clear();
            tbxTelefon.DataBindings.Clear();
            tbxEmail.DataBindings.Clear();
        }

        private void btnPoprzedni_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bs.MovePrevious();
            dgUpdate();
            rekord();
        }

        private void btnNastepny_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bs.MoveNext();
            dgUpdate();
            rekord();
        }

        private void btnPierwszy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bs.MoveFirst();
            dgUpdate();
            rekord();
        }

        private void btnOstatni_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bs.MoveLast();
            dgUpdate();
            rekord();
        }

        private void dgUpdate()
        {
            dg.ClearSelection();
            dg.Rows[bs.Position].Selected = true;
            rekord();
        }

        private void rekord()
        {
            lblRecords.Text = "Rekord " + bs.Position + " z " + (bs.Count - 1);
        }

        private void btnUaktualnij_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            da.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tbWlasciciel SET NAZWISKO = @NAZWISKO, IMIE = @IMIE, MIEJSCOWOSC = @MIEJSCOWOSC, KOD_POCZTOWY = @KOD_POCZTOWY, ADRES = @ADRES, TELEFON = @TELEFON, EMAIL = @EMAIL WHERE ID_WLASCICIELA = @ID_WLASCICIELA)", cs);
            da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@IMIE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbxImie.Text;
            da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@NAZWISKO", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbxNazwisko.Text;
            da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@MIEJSCOWOSC", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbxMiejscowosc.Text;
            da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@KOD_POCZTOWY", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbxKodPocztowy.Text;
            da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@ADRES", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbxAdres.Text;
            da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@TELEFON", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbxTelefon.Text;
            da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@EMAIL", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbxEmail.Text;
            da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID_WLASCICIELA", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[bs.Position][0];
            cs.Open();
            da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Dane w bazie danych zostały zaktualizowane!", "Aktualizacja danych");
            cs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove ")" at the end of your SqlCommand

Comment: @KyleC I suggest you write that as an answer.

Comment: Check at the end **"WHERE ID_WLASCICIELA = @ID_WLASCICIELA)"**.........remove closing brace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove ")" at the end of your SqlCommand. You have no starting `(` so it's telling you that the `)` at the end is invalid syntax, which it is.

Comment: @user1869274 now you should "accept" the answer by clicking that empty check-mark on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `)` in your `SqlCommand`. It is right of the `@ID_WLASCICIELA` parameter. You opened brackets once but you closed brackets twice.

Use this:

```
da.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tbWlasciciel SET NAZWISKO = @NAZWISKO, IMIE = @IMIE, MIEJSCOWOSC = @MIEJSCOWOSC, KOD_POCZTOWY = @KOD_POCZTOWY, ADRES = @ADRES, TELEFON = @TELEFON, EMAIL = @EMAIL WHERE ID_WLASCICIELA = @ID_WLASCICIELA", cs);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an extra ")" in your WHERE clause:

```
...@EMAIL WHERE ID_WLASCICIELA = @ID_WLASCICIELA)", cs)
```

where it should be:

```
...@EMAIL WHERE ID_WLASCICIELA = @ID_WLASCICIELA", cs)
```